# How do I  mount a directory in a remote machine using fuse?

Tags: linux, unix, linux-kernel, fuse

I am wondering how to use FUSE to mount a directory from a remote machin . The tutorial given in [this link](http://www.cs.nmsu.edu/~pfeiffer/fuse-tutorial/) mounts a local directory on to another local one. 
This essentially happens in the **fuse_main** function. Does anyone have an idea as how to do the same for a directory on a remote machine?

The function call is as follows

`fuse_main(argc, argv, &bb_oper, bb_data);`

Note: I cannot use sshfs

Thanks.

Comment: you are mixing abstraction levels. Looking at the fuse API is going to tell you _nothing_ about what filesystem drivers are implemented on top of it. Look here instead: http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/fuse/index.php?title=FileSystems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like any other network file system, FUSE is going to need an underlying transport layer. It can't help you unless something on the remote machine is able to handle the actual I/O for you.

In your fuse arguments, you set up handlers for the things you want the file system to be able to handle, e.g:

```
static struct fuse_operations const myfs_ops = {
        .getattr = my_getattr,
        .mknod = my_mknod,
        .mkdir = my_mkdir,
        .unlink = my_rm,
        .rmdir = my_rmdir,
        .truncate = my_truncate,
        .open = my_open,
        .read = my_read,
        .write = my_write,
        .readdir = my_readdir,
        .create = my_create,
        .destroy = my_destroy,
        .utime = my_utime,
        .symlink = my_symlink
};
```

That's code from one of my current FUSE implementations, re-written generically. As you can see, you'll need to at least implement `open`, `read`, `write` and `close` for a minimally functional FS.

Those members are functions, which do those operations. They can use HTTP, SSH, FTP, a custom protocol, whatever you want. But, you have to write them, and something on the remote server needs to respond to them.

To answer your question directly, FUSE (on it's own) isn't going to do what you want, unless you implement the functionality yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Too bad you can't use sshfs<sup>1</sup> - it is my weapon of choice (*iff I ever need to mount*, otherwise rsync does nicely).

You could try [`curlftpfs`](http://curlftpfs.sourceforge.net) which is capable of mounting an FTP 'share'.

Be sure to look at writing a `.netrc` (with proper permissions for security) so as to make this work *conveniently*

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Why not?</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You need to have some kind of network transport that the local and remote machines agree on for this: if not sshfs then smb or NFS or something.

It might help if you told everyone why you can't use sshfs.